# Pentaho - How to show complete date in line chart's X axis

Tags: charts, mdx, pentaho, linechart, pentaho-cde

I'm creating a Pentaho CDE dashboard and I'm having some difficulties in setup how the date is shown in a line chart. The below chart is what I have at this time:

[image: line chart]

As you can see, the X axis has numbers from 1-6, they are months. What I want do is show more information in this axis instead of simply 1, I want show "January / 2013" for example, but I have no idea of how can I achieve this.
My Mondrian schema for date dimension is this:

```
<Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="data_id" highCardinality="false" name="Data">
    <Hierarchy name="data" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="dimensao_data">
        </Table>
        <Level name="ano" visible="true" column="ano" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="semestre" visible="true" column="semestre" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeHalfYears" hideMemberIf="Never" captionColumn="labelSemestre">
        </Level>
        <Level name="quarto" visible="true" column="quarto" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters" hideMemberIf="Never" captionColumn="labelQuarto">
        </Level>
        <Level name="mes" visible="true" column="mes" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="Never" captionColumn="labelMes">
        </Level>
        <Level name="dia" visible="true" column="dia" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

and this is the MDX I'm using to retrieve data for the chart:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[valor]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY CrossJoin({[pagamento.forma].[moeda].MEMBERS}, {[Data.data].[mes].MEMBERS}) ON ROWS
FROM [Vendas]
WHERE {[Empresa.empresa].[MATRIZ]}
```

**NEW INFORMATION**

When I use debug mode I can see that Data.data don't comes only with month value and in String format:

```
[pvc.LineChart                 ]: DATA SOURCE SUMMARY
╔═════════╤═════════════════════╤═════════════╤══════════╗
║ Name    │ pagamento.forma     │ Data.data   │ valor    ║
╟─────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────╢
║ Label   │                     │             │          ║
╟─────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────╢
║ Type    │ String              │ String      │ Numeric  ║
╟─────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────╢
║ 1       │ "BOLETO BANCARIO"   │ "1"         │ 10469.15 ║
║ 2       │ "BOLETO BANCARIO"   │ "2"         │ 16279.45 ║
║ 3       │ "BOLETO BANCARIO"   │ "3"         │ 16279.45 ║
║ 4       │ "BOLETO BANCARIO"   │ "4"         │ 5810.3   ║
║ 5       │ "BOLETO BANCARIO"   │ "5"         │ 16279.45 ║
║ 6       │ "BOLETO BANCARIO"   │ "6"         │ 5810.3   ║
║ 7       │ "CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO" │ "1"         │ 10243.57 ║
║ 8       │ "CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO" │ "2"         │ 9178.03  ║
║ 9       │ "CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO" │ "3"         │ 10273.08 ║
║ 10      │ "CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO" │ "4"         │ 10110.4  ║
║ 11      │ "CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO" │ "5"         │ 10366.3  ║
║ 12      │ "CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO" │ "6"         │ 10768.75 ║
║ 13      │ "CARTÃO DE DÉBITO"  │ "1"         │ 15584.84 ║
║ 14      │ "CARTÃO DE DÉBITO"  │ "2"         │ 12400.53 ║
║ 15      │ "CARTÃO DE DÉBITO"  │ "3"         │ 13517.65 ║
╟─────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────╢
║ (15/41) │                     │             │          ║
╚═════════╧═════════════════════╧═════════════╧══════════╝
```

So, I believe the problem is with the result of Data.data. How can I purchase the complete date to show in chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that:

1. At the query level:

Define a Measure that holds the info you want to display:

```
With member [Measures].[Date Label] as [data].CurrentMember.Caption || " / " || Ancestor( [data].CurrentMember, [data].[ano]).Name
```

This should give you "2013 / January" as the output. Just filter out the columns you want to pass to the chart when defining the CDA query.

2. At the chart level.

You can change  what the chart displays by playing around with the PostFetch of the chart. Something like

```
function(data){
    var results = data.resultset.map(function(d){ 
        // Tweak the contents of each line of data here
        // You will want to take the value of d[0] and replace it by 
        // something else.
        return d;
    });
    data.resultset = results;
    return data
}
```

I prefer to have this type of thing done at the query level, it makes the dashboard simpler to understand and maintain. But it depends a lot on the specifics.